# Real Time Updates with Facebook C# SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, real-time-updates

Creating a MVC 3 web application, using the latest version of the C# Facebook SDK.  As of now having no trouble retrieving access token and the following user data, the next step in what I need to do is to use Facebook's Realtime Updates feature to make sure that my users Facebook data is up to date.  I am guessing that the C# SDK has something to deal with this, I just cant find anything.  Does anyone know of any good examples out there, or any tips to point me in the right direction?

Comment: just sent a pull request for including facebook subscription in the core. You could pull down that file for now and check it. https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/pull/219 waiting for code review before it gets merged.

Comment: Thanks @prabir for pointing this out to me, any estimates on when it gets merged and pushed out in a release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now handeled in the Facebook c# sdk, https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/pull/219 .